# Remove a string starting with \n or \U in R

Tags: r, gsub

I've a string like this:

```
x <- c("saw the revenant awesome experience must be seen on a big theatrical screen\ntherevenant","a lil sumn sumn i whipped up \U3e64653c\U3e30613c\U3e64623c\U3e64653c\U3e36623c\U3e61383ctherevenant")
```

How to remove everything starting with \n or \U in R using gsub()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iconv` to get rid of the \U characters and `gsub` to take care of the newlines.

```
x <- c("saw the revenant awesome experience must be seen on a big theatrical screen\ntherevenant","a lil sumn sumn i whipped up \U3e64653c\U3e30613c\U3e64623c\U3e64653c\U3e36623c\U3e61383ctherevenant")

> iconv(gsub("\\n", " ", x), to="ASCII", sub="")
[1] "saw the revenant awesome experience must be seen on a big theatrical screen therevenant"
[2] "a lil sumn sumn i whipped up therevenant"
```